# Javascript closure function doesn't return the right value

Tags: javascript, closures, return-value, settimeout, alert

I have a problem with my Javascript code and don't know why it doesn't run.

This is my timer:

```
var time = 0;
startTimer();

function startTimer(){
    setInterval(function(){
    time=time+1;
    },10);
}
```

This code here works (I run timeoutTester() while clicking on a button, then it alerts and shows me the time difference):

```
function timeoutTester(){
    var snap_time1 = time;
    setTimeout(function(){
        var snap_time2 = time;
        var diff = snap_time2-snap_time1;
        alert(diff);            //works: ~100 everytime...
    },1000);
}
```

But this code here doesn't work (I run testTimer() by clicking on a button):

```
function timeoutTester(){
    var snap_time1 = time;
    var result;
    setTimeout(function(){
        var snap_time2 = time;
        result = snap_time2-snap_time1;
    },1000);
    alert(result); //doesn't work! It always shows me: "undefined"
    return result;
}

function testTimer(){
    var counter = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        counter = counter + 1;
        alert(counter);         //works: 1,2,3,....
        var result = timeoutTester();
        alert(result);  //doesn't work! It always shows me: "undefined"
    }, 3000);
}
```

Do you know where the problem might be? (No error while debugging in browser!)

**UPDATE**:

I learned that alert(result); is executed immediately, while result has no value yet.

But since I'm calling timeoutTester() from the outside, I still need a return value from this function!

Any ideas?

Comment: The most asked question of the year this must be. Look for "async variable javascript" in Stack Overflow see if you find something.

Comment: @elclanrs: Thanks for the hint, but I still have now idea how to solve this issue...so I changed the question a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this done, you need to use a global:

```
var timeoutTesterResult;

function timeoutTester(){
    var snap_time1 = time;
    var result;
    setTimeout(function(){
        var snap_time2 = time;
        timeoutTesterResult = snap_time2-snap_time1;
        alert(timeoutTesterResult);                    //works: ~100
    },1000);
}
```

And a second timeout who gets this global only after it's set/changed:

```
function testTimer(){
    var counter = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        counter = counter + 1;
        alert(counter);         //works: 1,2,3,....
        timeoutTester();
        setTimeout("alert(timeoutTesterResult)",1000); //works: ~100
    }, 3000);
}
```

That's the "via global"-solution.

Answer (score 4):

In your last example (the one that doesn't work), calling `setTimeout(function()...)` does not execute the function immediately, but does return immediately. When it returns, `result` is still undefined because the function has not yet executed.

By the same token, the previous example (that has the call to `alert()` inside the timeout function) works because the call to `alert()` happens after `result` is assigned a value.

If for whatever reason you don't want to call `alert()` directly from within the timeout function, you could rewrite the last example as:

```
function timeoutTester(){
    var snap_time1 = time;
    setTimeout(function(){
        var snap_time2 = time;
        alertResult(snap_time2-snap_time1);
    },1000);
}
function alertResult(result) {
    alert(result);
}
```

(By the way, the call `startTimer(1000000000000);` looked scary until I realized that the argument was being ignored. :-).)

Comment: But is it possible to call the function from the outside and get a return value?